# Using prop from promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to return "r" when the promise is resolved, but the problem is that I can not access that prop from the second then. Any option?

The problem is in line 9, I can not access to r, but I need to return that. If a put a return inside the first r, I got `undefined`.

```
export async function FilmAPI(title) {
  if (Object.keys(title).length === 0) return null;
  var newTitle = title.split(/[ ]+/).join("+");

  const url = `films/?search=${newTitle}`;
  await api.get(url)
    .then(r => {
    console.log("TCL: FilmAPI -> r", r)
  }).then((response => {
    return r;
  }))
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })

}
```

Here is where I take the value return from FilmAPI

```
    export function searchNewFilmAction(title) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(newSearch());
    console.log(FilmAPI(title))
  };
}
```

Comment: And why is there a second `.then` in the first place? `return await api.get(url);` Also you are mixing two patterns either use `await` or `.then` way.

Comment: Just `return r` right after the `console.log` call.

Comment: Does the console.log print r or is also undefined?

Comment: why need response when not used it then((response => { }

Comment: Remove `}).then((response => {` and a single `)` after `return r;` and you should be set.

Comment: If I return r, when I get this value is undefined

Comment: then please show the api.get function @Salker

Comment: I edit main post where I take values from the FilmAPI function

Comment: but you are not returning anything, it just dispatches, and well, it changes the full answer, your problem is your action, `r´ is correctly identified as undefined, cause that is what is implicitly returned from your api

Comment: Can you also add the newSearch method? How are all these things connected, are you using react/redux (with any middlewares) as frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
export async function FilmAPI(title) {
  if (Object.keys(title).length === 0) return null;
  var newTitle = title.split(/[ ]+/).join("+");

  try {
    const url = `films/?search=${newTitle}`;
    const r = await api.get(url);
    console.log("TCL: FilmAPI -> r", r);
    return r;
  } catch(error ) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't like code only answers either, but honestly there ain't much to be explained regarding the refactor...I think...

Comment: It's let the Promise in pending

Comment: Well it doesn't matter anyhow anymore, the question changed quite a lot now :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using await, so don't use `then` and don't use `catch` but rather try catch

So rewrite your code as:

```
try {
  const r = await api.get(url);
  console.log('TCL: FilmAPI -> r', r );
  return r;
}
catch (ex) {
  console.Log( ex );
}
```

You could find some more info about the error handling [here](https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling), but basicly, when you are awaiting, you should use the try catch instead, if you are just using an async function, you should use the normal workflow with `catch()` and `then()`

Comment: return undefined,  the api launch to low.

Answer (score 0):

whey use then to access the element and do something for the data that coming

```
export async function FilmAPI(title) {
  if (Object.keys(title).length === 0) return null;
  var newTitle = title.split(/[ ]+/).join("+");

  const url = `films/?search=${newTitle}`;
try{
   let r=await api.get(url);
console.log('TCL: FilmAPI -> r', r );


    return r;}

    catch(error)  {
    console.log(error)
  }

}
```

Comment: return undefined

Comment: check if API it works fine or not is URL api.get(url);

Comment: If I make consolo.log(r) it return a good value, btw, when I get this result on FilmActions.js it's undefined  

This is the code: export function searchNewFilmAction(title) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(newSearch());
    FilmAPI(title).then(r => {
      console.log(r);
    })
  };

Answer (score 0):

Just return the response in the first then to get it as a param in the second then:

```js
class api {
  static get(_) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('resolved'), 1000);
    });
  }
}

async function FilmAPI(title) {
  if (Object.keys(title).length === 0) return null;
  var newTitle = title.split(/[ ]+/).join("+");

  const url = `films/?search=${newTitle}`;

  await api.get(url)
    .then(r => {
      console.log("r 1st then", r)
      return r;
    }).then(response => {
      console.log('r 2nd then: ' + response);
      return response;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}

let f = FilmAPI('SOME TITLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve the problem

```
export function searchNewFilmAction(title) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(newSearch());

    FilmAPI(title).then(response => {
      dispatch(newSearchSuccess(response.data.results));
    })
  };
}


export async function FilmAPI(title) {
  if (Object.keys(title).length === 0) return null;
  var newTitle = title.split(/[ ]+/).join("+");

  try {
    const url = `films/?search=${newTitle}`;
    const r = await api.get(url);
    console.log("TCL: FilmAPI -> r", r);
    return r;
  } catch(error ) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```